# Beginner PHP - Separating an array in php

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner at php and hopefully someone can help me. I have an array with 10 items and I need the **first element to be 1 instead of zero**. **I also need to have the array split into 2 columns beside each other with the first 5 elements in one column and the second 5 in the second.
I've tried using html but could not get it to work. When I use the slice in php the last element(5) in the first column disappears..
So let's say my array is as follows:

```
$farmland=array("Duck","Fox","Goose","Cow","Cat","Rabbit","Bull","Mouse","Sheep","Goat");
```

I need it to appear like this:

```
Duck       Rabbit
Fox        Bull
Goose      Mouse
Cow        Sheep
Cat        Goat
```

Comment: SHow some code first of all.

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code, or have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: `first element to be 1 instead of zero` why? What are you using the keys for? Show your current PHP usage(s).

Comment: " I need the first element to be 1 instead of zero." Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Also its important to know, an array in any programming language starts at 0, its just how arrays are made,  so if you have an array with 10 items, you will use the Array ID's of 0-9

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to split array into chunks is `array_chunk`:

```
$farmland = array("Duck","Fox","Goose","Cow","Cat","Rabbit","Bull","Mouse","Sheep","Goat");
$chunks = array_chunk($farmland, 5);  // get chunks with size of 5

print_r($chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

With array_chunk  you can split the array an two

```
$my_spliy_array =  array_chunk($farmland,5)
```

the in $my_split_array[0]  you have the first 5 element in  $my_split_array[1]  the last